# Error uploading PDF Files

Tags: java, file, exception

I am having a Web Application with a form to Upload Images/PDF. Then I will compress the image in the server and store in the database. When I am uploading the image,the Image is getting uploaded successfully. But When I try to Upload PDF it is throwing FileNotFoundException. Below is the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\762218\Desktop\w.pdf (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at com.dcx.service.writeup.dipap.common.ImageResize.calculateFile(Unknown Source)
```

The Exception is thrown in the below part of the code :

```
   private ByteArrayOutputStream calculateFile(File file) {

            long length = file.length();
         InputStream in = null;
          byte[] array = new byte[(int)length];
         try
        {
           in = new FileInputStream(file);              
            in.read(array);     
            System.out.println("innnnnnnnnnnn");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {     
            System.out.println("General Exception: "+e);        
            logger.info("Exception is"+e);          
          e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException ("File not found."+e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Note : 
1.I have placed both the image and the PDF in the same location. So there cant be any permission issues. 
2. The PDF is uploaded using the file input type in the HTML5. SO the path of the file is correct.

Please help in Resolving the issue. I couldn't find any reason for this error.

Comment: Stupid question, but I have to ask. You're *positive* that the file is in that spot and named `w.pdf`?

Comment: @snickers10m. Yes. The file is there. If I put the same path in my browser, the PDF opens.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());` to your code. It'll print *exactly* where the program is searching for the file. Maybe if it's not the same path as the one you want, we'll be able to pinpoint the problem.